# Como resolvo esse erro quando importo requests?

Tags: python

```
python3.2/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python3.2/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 147
    for prefix in [u'*.', u'.']:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: edita a pergunta colocando codigo do erro em questão para podermos ajudar, assim é dificil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce precisa usar a versão 2.7 do Python.
Fora que o erro acima não é do import do requests e sim do pyopenssl. Faça o pip install para python 3.

Remova o requests que voce instalou e rode o comando:

```
pip3 install requests
```